# understanding __construct($foo = null) and check if $foo is true then

Tags: php, oop

How `$mysettings` can be true while we are initializing it with null? is this a method to prevent SQL injection? It would be appreciated if you could explain the code below.

```
public function __construct($mysettings = null)
{
    $this->shop_version = Mage::getVersion();
    $this->moduleversion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Messagemodule')->version;
    $this->apppid = Mage::getStoreConfig('magemessage/appId');
    if (empty($this->apppid)) {
        $this->apppid = 'no-appId';
    }
    $this->connectortype = ($settingvariable = Mage::getStoreConfig('Messagemodule/magemessage/connector', 0)) ? $settingvariable : 'auto';
    if ($mysettings) {
        $this->connectortype = $mysettings;
    }
}
```

Comment: `null` is the default value. hopefully, he's passing something else.

Comment: It means it's an *optional* argument; if nothing is passed, it will be `null`.

Comment: Instead of direct jump on magento you must have to learn basic PHP

Comment: `default value` !== initial value.... suggested reading from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a default value in a PHP method (including a constructor), that's all it is - a **default**.

So if you have

```
class Foo {
  public function __construct($mysettings = null) {
    ...
  }
}
```

then you are providing two ways of constructing the class. You can either call

```
$foo = new Foo();
```

with no arguments, in which case `$mysettings` will be initialised to null. Or you can call

```
$settings = array('key' => 'value');
$foo = new Foo($settings);
```

in which case the `$settings` array will be passed into the new instance. The benefit this provides is that you don't need to provide an empty array to new instances for which you don't need custom settings; you can just omit the argument.

The check `if ($mysettings)...` in the class ensures that the settings are only used if they are provided - a PHP `if` statement can operate on lots of different types, not just booleans. In this case, if the variable is null, the condition will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code:

```
<?php

function required($something)
{
    echo $something;
}

required();
```

It throws a fatal error, because `$something` was required, but not passed. https://3v4l.org/fIKB9

Now look here:

```
<?php

function required($something = 'hello')
{
    echo $something;
}

required();
required(' R.Toward');
```

Which outputs `Hello R.Toward` https://3v4l.org/nQF8r

So in essence, it is a way of setting a default optional value.